# My tank is not draggable when I put the code into Google Drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I coded this (https://jsfiddle.net/Lb2f3405/) on jsfiddle, but now when I insert the code onto Google Drive, using Sublime Text, 
the tank cannot be dragged. Can someone explain why the code does not work?

I believe the error might be with the link tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Comment: Your tank is only draggable on a very small part of it. Can you give us the google drive link?

Comment: I am using my school network to test my code, and only people within the board can access it.